# Animated show in which the main characters wore watches, and something happened to make appliances and stuff attack

Tags: story-identification, anime, cartoon

I’m trying to figure out the name of a show that I have only ever seen one episode of. I was a little kid so the show was from either the late 90s or early 2000s. It was animated and in an anime style. No clue if it was actually a dubbed anime through. It scarred me for life and I desperately need to know what the show was.

The details I remember are that the main characters wore watches, I think, and something happened to make appliances and stuff attack. A mailbox grew legs and a Slushie Machine attacked as well.

If I see a screenshot I’ll know it. Please someone help me figure this out.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. You mentioned that the main characters wore watches; was there something special about those watches, and if so, what? Also, were the main characters kids or adults, and can you tell us anything else about them?

Comment: Thank you! I think they were older kids, maybe teens. And in the episode they were hanging out in the slushie shop. I think some kind of ray was used to make the objects mutate and attack. The main characters watches looked kinda futuristic too.

Comment: For some reason I though about Yokai Watch, but your premises don't seem to match.

Comment: Yeah, it definitely wasn’t that.